# Problem in downloading and browsing

Tags: malware, virus, internet

My downloads stop completing and some page in the browser appearing blank or with text only without css or js and so on, some program after complete return me a message when trying to start installing:

> The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the
>   program.

Also I can't install google chrome or antiviruses programs for example.

I have avira and do scan without results, What is the problem and is there any solution ?

Comment: Did you try using an alternate site for your download?

Comment: I use many websites some of them, installing google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Corrupted executable file:**

> The setup files are corrupted. Please obtain a new copy of the
>   program.

Usually the above error message appears when an executable file is missing some of the essential components/libraries that is essential to proceed the installation. It is very common that many files could be corrupted in some of the sites we download our free software. Or it could be a simple incomplete download issue. Try downloading your software from a different site.

**Browser Issue:**

If all your downloads stops before completion, then there is definitely something wrong with your browser. Try removing add-ons, external tool bars. There might be some uninvited fellow malwares sitting right there and infecting you. If that doesn't work try re-installing the browser.

Be careful when you install anything on your computer and watch out specially for the free add-ons and tool bars offered, there might be malwares included in that. You could identify  them by the weird behaviors such as pop ups and similar advertisements on your browsers no matter which site you visit.

**Anti virus:**

> I have avira and do scan without results

If your anti virus does not detect anything, then do not just come to a conclusion that you have no threats. Check if the anti virus software is updated. Every day there are lots of virus signatures are identified and updated in the anti virus database. Make sure that Web Anti-Virus option is enabled in your anti virus software. It will block/not allow the malicious websites or pop ups that can harm your computer.

**Suggestion:**

Clear your temporary/dump internet files from your computer. Perform a full system scan with your updated anti virus. Deal with the threats if you find any. Now try to download the software from the official site. Make sure the entire file is downloaded and then proceed with the installation. Your installation should be working fine by now.